# Trailhead Challenge..Help!

Tags: userlicense

I am trying to pass the challenge described in this link, https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en-MX/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_org?trail_id=force_com_dev_beginner#, but my 2 Salesforce licenses with the System Administrator profile, they are sold out, however when I check the users, there is only one with such a license, coincidentally mine. Unfortunately I can not perform the challenge because I can not find the other user with this license to disable it. If this has happened to someone and you can help me, please, I will be very grateful

Comment: You can just create a new Trailhead Playground, create two Users, both with your email and then proceed from there.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

Rolling up from comments with more details.

While you can use your personal Developer Edition Orgs for Trailhead Challenges, but in this scenario you can always create a new [Trailhead Playground](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/trailhead_playground_management/create-a-trailhead-playground) and utilize it specifically here. It's also recommended that you create a new Trailhead Playground for challenges so that you don't have to worry about quite a few things that you may not have in your personal Developer Edition Org, e.g., My Domain.

In your case, you can create a new Trailhead Playground, create two Users, both assigned to your email, so that you have credentials for both users. And then you can go ahead with the challenge to activate/deactivate the other one.